# Coding Style - Naming Conventions - Constants - What style does JQuery use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use the style JQuery uses:

I looked here:

[JQuery Coding Style](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines)

but could not find it.  Is it the same as PHP Zend style - All caps w/ underscores to seperate names?

I dowloaded the latest verion of JQuery and ran a search for constants but nothing came up.

Here is how I do my constants.

```
var Constant = 
{

/**
 *      Code Configuration
 */

    validate:                   1,

/**
 *      Paths Configuration
 */
    root:                       '',
    pictures_path:              '../pictures/',
    images_path:                '../images/',
    txt_path:                   '../text/',
    favicon:                    '../images/' + 'logo_small.ico',
    gateway_path:               'class.ControlEntry.php',

/**
 *      General
 */

    enter_key:                  13,
    second :                    1000,
    minute:                     60,
    hour:                       3600,
    day:                        43200,
    start:                      'hide_1',
    aml: 
    {
        "pass":                 0,
        "fail":                 1, 
        "undefinedU":           2
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question, No style is really "wrong". I personally use `camelCase` for client-side code and `underscore_spacing` for server-side code, and uppercase the first letter on `Classes` and server-side `Methods`.

Comment: I personally don't care how code is styled but I finally grew weary of people commenting on it so I decided to adhere to standards as it does not take much effort...going with Zend and Jquery as they seem to be pretty popular...thought I can't find the style that JQuery uses.

Comment: JavaScript does not have true constants, aside from the non-standard `const` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look through the jQuery API (and even the name `jQuery` itself), it is pretty noticeable that jQuery uses `camelCase` most of the time.

Here are a few examples.

All methds that are a result of seleting an element are camel-case:
addClass, removeClass, ajaxComplete, ajaxSend, after, add, append, appendTo

Most methods/properties that are members of jQuery are also camel-case, with a few exceptions.
ajax, ajaxSetup, boxModel, browser, contains, cssHooks, data

The exceptions are:
Deferred because it returns a new deferred object, and Callbacks because it returns a new Callbacks object.

Comment: jQuery doesn't use a constants object. look at lines 25-95, 97-319, 388-892, 1189-1386, 1333-1347, etc. It is a large file with a lot of different types of objects/variables/methods.